How to send notifications to a specific user registered with Azure Notification Hubs using FCM v1
This solution How is a messages sent to a specific user after it has been registred by the BackEnd using Azure Notification Hubs is able to send notifications to specific devices registered by the BackEnd server using Azure Notification Hubs.
However, FCM legacy APIs will soon no longer be supported, will this solution still work or will solution need to be updated to send using FCM v1?
Will it be a similar approach to send notifications to specific users?


Will it be a similar approach to send notifications to specific users?

The overall workflow for sending notifications to specific users will remain similar as given in < my SO solution, but there will be changes in the backend interaction with FCM.

When the backend server receives the FCM token from the Android app it registers the FCM token with Azure Notification Hub. Then the FCM token is associated with the appropriate user ID using tags.

The structure of the Installation object might need to be updated to comply with FCM v1 requirements.
var installation = new Installation
{
    InstallationId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
    Platform = NotificationPlatform.Fcm, // Here specify the platform as FCM
    PushChannel = deviceToken,
    Tags = new List<string> { $"userId:{userId}" }
};

You can get the notification as per UserID:

